# Why does only_if Chef::Config['solo'] also run on server?

Tags: chef-infra

I've tried using Chef::Config['solo'] to perform an action only when run locally, such as running kitchen tests. However, when running on another host, it still installs the epel-release package, which I would not like to do. Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

```
# added to pass kitchen test
package 'epel-release' do
  action :upgrade
  only_if Chef::Config['solo']
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you mean `only_if { Chef::Config['solo'] }`. Without the `{}` it's interpreted as a command string to run.

Also solo vs. not isn't specifically related to "locally", it's `chef-solo` vs `chef-client` as the original command.

Comment: Would there be a way to run that resource only in a kitchen test, and not on the client itself when using chef-client?

Comment: `if ENV['TEST_KITCHEN']` or similar. That env var is set automatically by Test Kitchen.

Comment: Thank you! This appears to be what I was looking for. Voting best answer since it resolves my issue.